# Blank form being submitted Classic ASP

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form that when submitted gets emailed. The form uses JavaScript for validation. Classic ASP processes the form i.e. gets the data entered, creates and then sends the email. There have been reports that blank forms are being submitted. Just the title and the logo are being sent. No labels and no data is included. I tried recreating this issue and cannot. I have to fill in all required fields prior to submitting. Anyone ever experience this before?

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing Javascript validation it is done on the client side, this is very easy to circumvent by just posting to the ASP page without the browser (or using certain browser plugins). This could be the source of your empty forms.
Good validation has to be done on the server side, in this case on the ASP side.

Answer (score 0):

'in need of help' is right. This happens alot with bots on the net. They find your form and submit them without using javascript. You could try disabling javascript and see what happens if you submit the form.

Also you should always add server side validation. If only for checking if the fields are filled at all.